# How to frame 2 url on same call on simultenusly

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

How to frame 2 url on same ajax call on simultenusly to set the value in different div id. i have tried to use below 2 diffrent function empajax & studentajax functions.
Please help to resolve my issue. Requirement is need to set the empname and studentname (please check the handleresponse function)

```
function empajax(method,nameId)
{
   url='college/cat/employee.jsp'+"?nameId="+nameId;
   if(method == 'POST'){
        http.open(method,url,true);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        http.send(null);
    }   
}

function handleResponse(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        if(response){
            $("#empname").html(response);
          }
    }      
}

function studentajax(method,nameId)
{
   url='college/cat/student.jsp'+"?nameId="+nameId;
   if(method == 'POST'){
        http.open(method,url,true);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleStudentResponse;
        http.send(null);
    }   
}


function handleStudentResponse(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        if(response){
            $("#studentname").html(response);
          }
    }      
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working about this? Are the `div`s not being filled with the values? Are the values incorrect? Are they not occurring at the same time? We don't know what problem you're having.

Comment: div is not being filled with values also page is breaking... unable to get any error in the backend